# Query function symbol for existence

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

I can use `sYmbol.Browse.Function` to browse through function symbols loaded to the internal TRACE32 symbol database; quoting the [General Reference [S]](http://www2.lauterbach.com/pdf/general_ref_s.pdf):

> `sYmbol.Browse.Function`
>
> Lets you browse through the list of functions that have been loaded to
>   the internal TRACE32 symbol database with `Data.LOAD`.

I'm writing a util that reads user input (function symbol name), and it would be helpful to block user for going forward in case of entering an invalid function symbol. I'm currently using `Trace.Find ADDress <name_of_function>` followed by querying `FOUND()`.

*Question:*

- What would be the idiomatic way to *query* a specific function symbol name for its existence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sYmbol.EXIST(<symbol>)`. Citing the [General Reference [S]](http://www2.lauterbach.com/pdf/general_ref_s.pdf):

> `sYmbol.EXIST(<symbol>)`
>
> Boolean function. Returns `true` when the symbol exists.
>
> ```
> IF sYmbol.EXIST(main)
>     GO.direct main
> ```